# how to modify ORB source in opencv 2.4.9?

Tags: c++, opencv

i have built the openCV version 2.4.9. I want to modify the ORB library for detect and compute function.

```
orb.detect(img_object, keypoints_object)
orb.compute(img_object, keypoints_object, descriptors_object)
```

i tried to search it in `orb.cpp` in `\opencv\sources\modules\features2d\src` but i didn't found these functions. Anyone know how to find these functions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The basic interface should be in

`opencv/sources/modules/features2d/src/detectors.cpp` as `void FeatureDetector::detect( const Mat& image, vector<KeyPoint>& keypoints, const Mat& mask )`

same for `opencv\sources\modules\features2d\src\descriptors.cpp` and `void DescriptorExtractor::compute( const Mat& image, vector<KeyPoint>& keypoints, Mat& descriptors )`